# Safari width percentage transition error

Tags: html, css, safari

I am having trouble with this. I need your help.This is driving me insane.

I created zooming effect by setting image width to 100% and border set to different width on hover. The effect seems to work nicely on Chrome firefox ie but it doesn't work on safari.
Not exactly sure where the problem is.
It looks like the image is not scaling correctly. 
Also last item in a row will push the next row when on hover. Again only in Safari.

http://www.innohome.kr/product/list.html?cate_no=31

Here is HTML

```
<div class="xans-element- xans-product xans-product-listnormal">

<ul class="prdList">
    <li id="anchorBoxId_5" class="xans-record-">
        <div class="prdList1">
            <a name="anchorBoxName_5" href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=5&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="prdImg"><img src="http://www.innohome.kr/web/product/small/innofeel60_5.png" alt=""/>
             &#160;</a>   

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="caption_top">
                    <a href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=5&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="name">샘플상품 5</a>
             <div class="icon"> <img src="http://img.echosting.cafe24.com/design/common/icon_rec.gif"  class="icon_img" alt="추천" /> <img src="http://img.echosting.cafe24.com/design/common/icon_new_p.gif"  class="icon_img" alt="신상품" /> </div>
                 </div>
                <strong class="price">
                    <span class="custom ">25,000원</span>25,000원                   </strong> 
                <span class="summary_desc"></span>
                <span class="displaynone date"></span>
             </div>
        </div>


    </li>

    <li id="anchorBoxId_32" class="xans-record-">
        <div class="prdList1">
            <a name="anchorBoxName_32" href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=32&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="prdImg"><img src="http://www.innohome.kr/web/product/small/innofeel60_32.jpg" alt=""/>
           &#160;</a>               

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="caption_top">
                    <a href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=32&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="name">chair 5</a>
                      <div class="icon">   </div>

                 </div>

                <strong class="price">
                    <span class="custom ">30,000원</span>30,000원                   </strong> 
                <span class="summary_desc"></span>
                <span class="displaynone date"></span>
             </div>

       </div>
    </li>
    <li id="anchorBoxId_31" class="xans-record-">
        <div class="prdList1">
            <a name="anchorBoxName_31" href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=31&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="prdImg"><img src="http://www.innohome.kr/web/product/small/innofeel60_31.jpg" alt=""/>
           &#160;</a>               

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="caption_top">
                    <a href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=31&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="name">chair 4</a>
                      <div class="icon">   </div>

                 </div>

                <strong class="price">
                    <span class="custom ">30,000원</span>30,000원                   </strong> 
                <span class="summary_desc"></span>
                <span class="displaynone date"></span>
             </div>

       </div>
    </li>
    <li id="anchorBoxId_30" class="xans-record-">
        <div class="prdList1">
            <a name="anchorBoxName_30" href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=30&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="prdImg"><img src="http://www.innohome.kr/web/product/small/innofeel60_30.jpg" alt=""/>
           &#160;</a>               

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="caption_top">
                    <a href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=30&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="name">chair3</a>
                      <div class="icon">   </div>

                 </div>

                <strong class="price">
                    <span class="custom ">30,000원</span>30,000원                   </strong> 
                <span class="summary_desc"></span>
                <span class="displaynone date"></span>
             </div>

       </div>
    </li>
    <li id="anchorBoxId_29" class="xans-record-">
        <div class="prdList1">
            <a name="anchorBoxName_29" href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=29&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="prdImg"><img src="http://www.innohome.kr/web/product/small/innofeel60_29.jpg" alt=""/>
           &#160;</a>               

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="caption_top">
                    <a href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=29&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="name">chair 2</a>
                      <div class="icon">   </div>

                 </div>

                <strong class="price">
                    <span class="custom ">30,000원</span>30,000원                   </strong> 
                <span class="summary_desc"></span>
                <span class="displaynone date"></span>
             </div>

       </div>
    </li>
    <li id="anchorBoxId_28" class="xans-record-">
        <div class="prdList1">
            <a name="anchorBoxName_28" href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=28&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="prdImg"><img src="http://www.innohome.kr/web/product/small/innofeel60_28.jpg" alt=""/>
           &#160;</a>               

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="caption_top">
                    <a href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=28&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="name">table 6</a>
                      <div class="icon">   </div>

                 </div>

                <strong class="price">
                    <span class="custom ">5,000원</span>5,000원                   </strong> 
                <span class="summary_desc"></span>
                <span class="displaynone date"></span>
             </div>

       </div>
    </li>
    <li id="anchorBoxId_27" class="xans-record-">
        <div class="prdList1">
            <a name="anchorBoxName_27" href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=27&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="prdImg"><img src="http://www.innohome.kr/web/product/small/innofeel60_27.JPG" alt=""/>
           &#160;</a>               

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="caption_top">
                    <a href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=27&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="name">table 5</a>
                      <div class="icon">   </div>

                 </div>

                <strong class="price">
                    <span class="custom ">5,000원</span>5,000원                   </strong> 
                <span class="summary_desc"></span>
                <span class="displaynone date"></span>
             </div>

       </div>
    </li>
    <li id="anchorBoxId_26" class="xans-record-">
        <div class="prdList1">
            <a name="anchorBoxName_26" href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=26&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="prdImg"><img src="http://www.innohome.kr/web/product/small/innofeel60_26.JPG" alt=""/>
           &#160;</a>               

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="caption_top">
                    <a href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=26&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="name">table 4</a>
                      <div class="icon">   </div>

                 </div>

                <strong class="price">
                    <span class="custom ">5,000원</span>5,000원                   </strong> 
                <span class="summary_desc"></span>
                <span class="displaynone date"></span>
             </div>

       </div>
    </li>
    <li id="anchorBoxId_25" class="xans-record-">
        <div class="prdList1">
            <a name="anchorBoxName_25" href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=25&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="prdImg"><img src="http://www.innohome.kr/web/product/small/innofeel60_25.jpg" alt=""/>
           &#160;</a>               

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="caption_top">
                    <a href="http://innohome.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=25&cate_no=12&display_group=1" class="name">table 3</a>
                      <div class="icon">   </div>

                 </div>

                <strong class="price">
                    <span class="custom ">5,000원</span>5,000원                   </strong> 
                <span class="summary_desc"></span>
                <span class="displaynone date"></span>
             </div>

       </div>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>
```

Here is css

```
.xans-product-listnormal {
    border: 1px solid #ebebe8; 
    position: relative; 
    margin-bottom: 0px;}
.xans-product-listnormal h2{}
.xans-product-listnormal ul { 
    clear:both; 
    zoom:1; 
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:center} 
.xans-product-listnormal ul:after {
    content:""; 
    display:block; 
    clear:both; }
.xans-product-listnormal ul li { 
    float:left;
    padding:0 0 0px 0;
    position:relative; 
    width:25%;} 
.xans-product-listnormal ul li .prdList1 {
    vertical-align:top; 
    padding:0px 0 0 0px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#fff;
    border:20px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
            transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.xans-product-listnormal ul li .prdList1:hover {
    border:10px solid #ebebe8;}
.xans-product-listnormal ul .prdImg {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%}
.xans-product-listnormal ul .prdImg>img {width:100%;}

.xans-product-listnormal ul .caption{
    width:85%; 
    margin: 0 auto;}
.xans-product-listnormal ul .name { 
    margin:0px auto; 
    padding:0px 5px 5px 5px; 
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
    font:11px/17px 돋움;
    color:#5A5A5A; 
    letter-spacing: -1px; 
     border-bottom:1px solid #dbdbdb;}
.xans-product-listnormal ul li .prdList1 span.summary_desc {
    display:block;
     padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;
     margin:0px auto;
      text-align:left;
      font:11px/14px 돋움;
      color:#9C9C9C;
      padding:10px 0px 0 0px;
      letter-spacing: -1px;}

.xans-product-listnormal ul .icon { 
    padding:0px 10px;
    display:block;
     vertical-align:middle;
     text-align:right; 
     height:15px}

.xans-product-listnormal ul .icon img {
    vertical-align:middle;}
.xans-product-listnormal ul .price {  display:block;
 text-align:left;
 font:bold 11px/15px 맑은 고딕;
 color:#ff825e;
 padding:5px 10px 10px; }
.xans-product-listnormal ul .price span.custom  {
    text-align:right; 
    text-decoration:line-through;
    font:italic 11px/15px 맑은 고딕;
    color:#888;
    padding:0 5px 0 0px ;}


.xans-product-listnormal .prdList ul.prdColor { margin:5px 0; }
.xans-product-listnormal .prdList ul.prdColor li { width:8px; 
    height:8px; 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0 2px 2px 0;
     border:1px solid #969696; }
.xans-product-listnormal .prdList ul.prdColor li span { 
    display:block; height:100%; }

.xans-product-listnormal ul .xans-product-listitem { min-width:0; }
.xans-product-listnormal ul .xans-product-listitem { margin:0; }
.xans-product-listnormal ul .xans-product-listitem li { 
    overflow:hidden; 
    float:none;
     width:auto;
      padding:0;
       text-align:center; }
.xans-product-listnormal ul .xans-product-listitem li .title { font-weight:normal; }
```

Any idea what is causing this issue? Any solution?

Appreciate any help I could get.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give us some code to work with, I cannot dive into your website source code and dig through line after line of source code until I find the bug, give me the relative html/css/js and I can fix your problem. If you ignore this request I have no choice but to flag your problem.

Comment: I am sorry. I will get the relevant code for you. thank you.

Comment: Can you give a better description of the problem? "it looks like the image is not scaling correctly" is not enough; I can't see any differences in how Safari behaves on the website. Unless I'm looking with the wrong version of Safari...